# Prevent re-rendering when child components list expands

Tags: reactjs, render

In the following example, every click of the button should only render the next `Number` component, but instead it re-renders the whole list again. I would like to know the best practice to prevent the previous one from re-rendering. Thank you.

```
const Number = (props) =>{return (<div> {props.number} </div>)}

const NumberListUpTo = () =>{

 const [listLength, setListLength] = useState(1);

 return(
 <>
  <button onClick = {() => setListLength(listLength + 1)}>add one more</button>
  {
   Array.from({length: listLength}, (v, i) => i).map(
   (i) => (<Number number = {i} />))
  }
 </>)
}
```

Comment: Impossible, entire list have to rerender

Comment: Yes from the code the result is re-rendering of the entire list, but I am asking for a way to optimize performance: either by using React.memo, local storage, etc. I am seeking for the best practice to modify the code from current scenario.

Comment: This `Number` component doesn't do anything computation intensive so you shouldn't try to optimize it. Optimize components when you see that the UI is unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to memoize your components.
2. You should always provide a `key` for React components when you are rendering an array of elements.

**Edit:**
As React documentation says:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Do not try to prevent renders or memoize every component. Try to optimize your code whenever you there is a performance issue. Optimization in React, using `memo`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`, etc) comes at a price; they take resources and may even slow down your app.